# Show delete link for only last record on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have used a before_destroy callback to allow only the deletion of the last record.  How can I only display the delete link for the last record on the index page of a standard scaffold?

```
 <% @records.each do |record| %>
 <tr>
<td><%= record.title %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', record %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_record_path(record) %></td>
<% if last_record? %><td><%= link_to 'Destroy', record, method: :delete'%></td><% end %>
</tr>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= record.title %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', record %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_record_path(record) %></td>

    <% if record == @records.last %>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', record, method: :delete %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```